# Hide App title and icon/logo in Android DialogFragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm having trouble hiding the titlebar and logo when I show an Android `DialogFragment` subclass. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For hiding title,logo/icon :**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
}
```

**For giving new width and height to layout :**

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    int dialogWidth = 800;
    int dialogHeight = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
    window.setLayout(dialogWidth, dialogHeight);
    window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    super.onStart();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line of code in your `HelpDialog.onCreateView(...)`

```
getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

This way you're explicitly asking to get a window without title :)

Edited:

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                                   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
myview.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

layoutparams(widht,height) . got it ?

Comment: Thanks for your help,If i am adding `"getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`" to my code means ,size of layout width is decreasing?,is there any possibility to set layoutwidth in program?